# PGFGantt: change name of week

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

Currently I am preparing a Gantt-Diagramm with *pgfgantt*. In Germany it is common to use the abbreviation *KW* (Kalendarwoche) which translates to *calendar week*. I would like to change *week 1, 2, ...* to *KW 1, 2, ...* in my Gantt-Diagramm.

What I have tried before:

- find something like *pgfcalendarweekname* in the tikz manual to define a new name as I have done with the weekday and month names (wasn't able to find *pdfcalendarweekname*)
- Use the translator package (didn't change *week* to *Woche* which would have been fine)
- Use the polyglossia package (XeLatex messes up my given template)

edit: I tried to include the MWE as code but I wasn't able to using Firefox on a Mac

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{babel}  

\usepackage{pgfgantt}  

%German abbreviations  
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter#1{%  
 \ifcase#1M\or D\or M\or D\or F\or S\or S\fi%  
}  
%German abbreviations; Use S. instead of September  
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%  
 \ifcase#1 Dezember \or Januar\or Februar\or März\or April\or Mai\or Juni\or Juli \or August \or S. \or Oktober \or November \or Dezember\fi%  
}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{ganttchart}[  
hgrid,%  
vgrid,%  
time slot format=simple,%  
time slot format/start date =2015-09-28%  
]{1}{18}  
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name,week=40 day, weekday=letter} \\  
\ganttgroup{1. Gruppe}{1}{18} \\  
\ganttbar{1.1 Arbeitspaket}{1}{2}\\  
\ganttbar{1.2 Arbeitspaket}{3}{18}  
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}  
\end{ganttchart}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: About the code markup: you had done the right thing, but there is one caveat -- it doesn't work when placed immediately after lists. That is why I added the horizontal bar in my edit. As you can see from percusse's edit it works fine now that you have the "edit: .." line after the list. See [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327) for an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That text string is defined by `pgfgantt`, not `pgf` itself, and is adjustable via the `calendar week text` key. The default value is `Week~\currentweek`. You can add `calendar week text={KW~\currentweek}` to the options of individual `ganttchart`s, or use `\ganttsett` to set it globally.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{babel}  

\usepackage{pgfgantt}  

%German abbreviations  
\def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter#1{%  
 \ifcase#1M\or D\or M\or D\or F\or S\or S\fi%  
}  
%German abbreviations; Use S. instead of September  
\def\pgfcalendarmonthname#1{%  
 \ifcase#1 Dezember \or Januar\or Februar\or März\or April\or Mai\or Juni\or Juli \or August \or S. \or Oktober \or November \or Dezember\fi%  
}  

% This line is added
\ganttset{calendar week text={KW~\currentweek}}

\begin{document}  

\begin{ganttchart}[  
hgrid,%  
vgrid,%  
time slot format=simple,%  
time slot format/start date =2015-09-28%
]{1}{18}  
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name,week=40 day, weekday=letter} \\  
\ganttgroup{1. Gruppe}{1}{18} \\  
\ganttbar{1.1 Arbeitspaket}{1}{2}\\  
\ganttbar{1.2 Arbeitspaket}{3}{18}  
\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}  
\end{ganttchart}  

\end{document}
```